# how to do sorting of column 3, and change corresponding value of column 2 in new file using shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I want to do sorting using `sort` command.
Input file is `1.txt`

```
      1    2   2
      1    3   5.5
      1    4   1.5
      1    5    2.2
      2    1    1.1
      2    3    0.7
      2    4    0.9
      2    5    0.4
```

out file should be

```
  1    4   1.5
  1    2   2
  1    5   2.2
  1    3   5.5
  2    5   0.4
  2    3   0.7
  2    4   0.9
  2    1   1.1
```

column 3 should be sorted and corresponding second column should change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just want to do a numeric sort on two keys:

```
$ sort -n -k1 -k3 file
      1    4   1.5
      1    2   2
      1    5    2.2
      1    3   5.5
      2    5    0.4
      2    3    0.7
      2    4    0.9
      2    1    1.1
```

`-n` does a numeric sort, first on field 1 `-k1` and then on field 3 `-k3`.

Answer (score -1):

try then tune this one:

```
cat 1.txt | sed -E -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/ /g' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $1, $3, $2}' | sort | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "; OFS=" "} {print $1, $3, $2}'
```

- sed - unify the column separators to a single space
- awk - change order of columns
- sort - sort 'em accordingly
- awk - change order of columns back to normal

Answer (score -1):

Here is one using GNU awk. It reads the data in memory and sorts while outputing so a huge file may cause you problems:

```
$ awk '{
    a[$1][$3]=$0
}
END { 
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
    for(i in a)
        for(j in a[i])
            print a[i][j]
}' file
```

Output (cleaned off the leading space after awk output):

```
1    4   1.5
1    2   2
1    5    2.2
1    3   5.5
2    5    0.4
2    3    0.7
2    4    0.9
2    1    1.1
```